# "Do you agree or disagree" and "To what extent do you agree or disagree" question?

Tags: ielts

I just want to know if i can **partially agree** in "Do you agree or disagree" question type in IELTS test. In "**To what extent** do you agree or disagree" question type we are allowed to partially agree an argument but i am not sure about the former one.

Comment: I’m sorry, JinJin – this is not the place to ask this. ELU addresses how the English language usually works, not how certain exam boards like their questions answering.  So I must vote to close this question because it asks about how an arbitrary examination board specifies its examination requirements. // Also, contributors have been known to get their answers wrong here. If an IELTS administrator, or tutor,  gives you advice, they can be held accountable if it's incorrect.

Comment: In "Do you agree or disagree" questions, you should present arguments for and against, **but**, in the conclusion you should state whether, **on the whole**, you are in agreement or disagreement. In   "To what extent do you agree or disagree" questions, the conclusion should reflect your degree of agreement/disagreement. (I see the question as the use of two common phrases and, basically, independent of the board in question. I would keep it open.)

Comment: If you agree *at all*, then you agree. If you disagree *at al*l, then you disagree. It is, however, possible to have no opinion either way, and neither agree *nor* disagree. (It's also possible to partially agree, but also partially disagree, making it ambiguous.) But if the test only allows for agreement or disagreement, then there is no way of providing those other possibilities as an answer. Once you have determined *if* you agree or disagree, *then* you can provide additional detail by saying *to what extent* that agreement or disagreement is.

Comment: The first question is assumed by the second, but while the first question seems to be a limiting binary choice, the second question appears more free-form, providing the ability to give more detail. (Unless it's just a scale of 1–10. If so, that's a little less of a limiting binary, but still imposes constraints.)